# how to add text in a list view container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

how to add text below the each container like the image showing below. appreciate your help on this. ...... ....................................... ....................... ................................................ ................. .............. ........... ...............

```
final List<String> containerImages = [
    'asset/images/canada3.jpg',
    'asset/images/canada1.jpg',
    'asset/images/canada2.jpg',
    'asset/images/canada2.jpg',
  ];

 Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 150,
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return SizedBox(width: 20,);
                    },
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        width: 120,
                        child: Image.asset(containerImages[index],fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      );

                    },
                  ),

                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a container, return a column widget and add text below the image container

```
final List<String> containerImages = [
    'asset/images/canada3.jpg',
    'asset/images/canada1.jpg',
    'asset/images/canada2.jpg',
    'asset/images/canada2.jpg',
  ];
final List<String> imageTitles = [
"content1", "content2", "content3", "content4"

 Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 250,
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return SizedBox(width: 20,);
                    },
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                       children: [
               Container(
                        width: 120,
                        child: Image.asset(containerImages[index],fit:BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
              Text("${imageTitles[index]}")
                       ]
                      );

                    },
                  ),

                ),
              )
```

Comment: I got >> A RenderFlex overflowed by 95 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: Increase the height from 150 to 250 for the container. Giving a fixed height may cause issues in some devices. My suggestion is to keep the image size constant and restrict the text to a specific number of characters so all cards remain same.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code, I have used NetworkImages so you used your images and also used your Texts, you will manage width and height of container on your need

your image lists:

```
final List listImages = [
    'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/27/11/23/cat-7094808__340.jpg',
    'https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/5C51E427-1715-44E6-9B14D9487D7B7F2D_source.jpg',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg',
  ];
```

Your Widget:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Container(
    height: 200,
    child: ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        );
      },
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: listImages.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              20,
            ),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 150,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(
                          10,
                        ),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(
                          10,
                        ),
                      ),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          listImages[index],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Awesome Product From Person ${index.toString()}',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

Your result screen->  [image]